# django FieldError at /search/ Cannot resolve keyword 'searchkeyword'

Tags: django, filter, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I am working thru the Practical Django Projects book and am stumped. The book is for an earlier version of Django. I am using v1.3.

The problem is in the view, at 'search_*keyword*_keyword__in...'

```
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', '') 
    keyword_results = results = []
    if query:
        keyword_results = FlatPage.objects.filter(searchkeyword__keyword__in=query.split()).distinct()
        results = FlatPage.objects.filter(content__icontains=query)
    return render_to_response('search/search.html',
                    {'query' : query,
                     'keyword_results': keyword_results,
                     'results' : results })
```

The models.py is

```
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from django.db import models

class SearchKeyword(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    page = models.ForeignKey(FlatPage)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.keyword
```

The full error is:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'searchkeyword' into field. Choices are: content, enable_comments, id, registration_required, sites, template_name, title, url
```

Which I think are the options for FlatPages. It doesn't seem like the foreign key relationship is being found.

Any ideas what could be wrong or how to correctly do the lookup?  Thanks.

Here is the admin.py in case it has some bearing:

```
from django.contrib.flatpages.admin import FlatPageAdmin
from django.contrib import admin
from cms.search.models import SearchKeyword
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage

# Define an inline admin descriptor for SearchKeywords model
class SearchKeywordInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SearchKeyword

# Define a FlatPageAdmin class
class ExtendedFlatPageAdmin(FlatPageAdmin):
    inlines = [
        SearchKeywordInline,
    ]

# Re-register FlatPageAdmin
admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(FlatPage, ExtendedFlatPageAdmin)
```

Comment: Has the app containing SearchKeyword been added to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was:

```
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from django.db import models
```

The models needs to come first, like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
```

I think what was happening is the FlatPage instance was being created before the ForeignKey was created, therefore the SearchKeyword attribute was not available to FlatPage.

Answer (score 0):

The reverse relationship for your ForeignKey would be named `searchkeyword_set` (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects), so your queryset should have `searchkeyword_set__keyword__in` as a a parameter (or you can use related_name.

If that didn't work, you should check that you have done manage.py syncdb ?

Comment: Adding _set did not help. Using related_name gave the same results.

Comment: I have ran manage.py syncdb several times without errors.

I think you are correct in looking at the ForeignKey relationship because if I comment out the line in question, the next line works fine - which is another filter without a ForeignKey.

Comment: The only difference I can see between the sample in the link you provided and my code is the ForeignKey points to FlatPage instead of a model in the same file.

Comment: I have worked through the examples on the page you mentioned. Thanks. I created a 'dummy' FlatPage2 model within the search app. I am able to execute: FlatPage2.objects.filter(fkpage2__keyword__contains='one') where fkpage2 is the related name of the ForeignKey. But I get the error when I try it with Django's FlatPage: Flatpage.objects.filter(fkpage__keyword__contains='one'). The error is "FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'fkpage' into field. Choices are: content, enable_comments, id, registration_required, sites, template_name, title, url".  How do I do relationships across apps?